# nestjs can't find ejs module - Could not find a declaration file for module 'ejs'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, puppeteer, ejs

Well, I'm trying to render an ejs file as a string to convert it to PDF using the puppeteer library on using a nestjs endpoint.

But when it runs, it throws:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'renderFile')`

Here's the code:

```
import { Controller, Get, HttpException, HttpStatus, Param, Body, Post, Header } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import ejs from 'ejs';

@Post()
@Header('content-type', 'application/pdf')
@Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=invoice.pdf')
getPDFInvoice(@Body() user) {
  const userData = { 
    firstname: "linus",
    lastname: "torvalds",
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    mob: "900-900-9000"
  };

  let browser;
  (async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const html = await ejs.renderFile("invoice.ejs", { user: userData });
    await page.setContent(html);
    const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: "A4" });

    return pdf;
  })()
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      throw {};
    })
    .finally(() => browser?.close());
}
```

In VSC, hovering `'ejs'` throws this warning:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'ejs'. 'c:/.../node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ejs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ejs';`

I executed `npm install ejs`. I also tried with `npm i --save-dev @types/ejs` but it didn't work either.

I read somewhere that ejs wasn't made for work properly on typescript. But at this point idk what to think.

Comment: what about `import * as ejs from 'ejs';`

Comment: also you can see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs that the type defs of `ejs` are defined at `@types/ejs`